# Alphabetical Category order?

Tags: categories

I've recently imported some data that resulted in the creation of hundreds of categories. Unfortunately, within the CMS, they all list in ID order, making this very difficult to manage.

There used to be a way to change the order of categories in EE2. You had a "Master Sort Order" where could choose alphabetical or custom. Is there any way to do this in EE6+, or at least get them to alphabetical order within the system without manually dragging them into the correct place?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this programmatically via:

{exp:channel:categories style="linear" orderby="category_name" sort="asc"}
    <a href="#">{category_name}</a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need it alphabetized within the content manager itself. It's a list of hundreds of school names in completely random order. It's maddening to try and assign any entry to a category, and any new categories automatically go the bottom. I need an option to have the categories stay in alphabetical order without having to manually place them in order.